# Is it possible to find random.seed value after having run the code several times and getting random results

Tags: python-3.x

I have run my code several times getting different values for random.choice eventually I want to settle for one value in my last run. Is there a way to find what value(X) to put in random.seed(X) so that I get the same value from next run onwards.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to extract a seed but you can extract a state

```
import json 
import random 
try: 
    with open("randseed", "r") as f: 
        seed = json.loads(f.read()) 
except: 
    seed = random.getstate() 
    with open("randseed", "w+") as f: 
        f.write(json.dumps(seed)) 
    seed = json.loads(json.dumps(seed)) 
seed[1] = tuple(seed[1]) 
random.setstate(seed)
```

this is reading a state out of randseed if it exists or saves the current state to randseed.

And uses json to save the object.